# Converting ms word files to .docx; what's the point of the .Convert function?

Tags: vb.net, ms-word

I am trying to figure out if the .Convert function is actually doing anything, what is the difference between these 2 code snippets? Just saving the document in the new file format seems to automatically convert everything I need.

Difference between this:

```
 oDoc = oWord.Documents.Open(FileName:=sOldFile, AddToRecentFiles:=False, Visible:=False, ReadOnly:=False, OpenAndRepair:=True)     
  oDoc.Convert()
  oDoc.Save()
  oDoc.Close()
```

And this:

```
  oDoc = oWord.Documents.Open(FileName:=sOldFile, AddToRecentFiles:=False, Visible:=False, ReadOnly:=False, OpenAndRepair:=True)
  oDoc.SaveAs(FileName:=sNewFile, FileFormat:=p_eDestType, AddToRecentFiles:=False, ReadOnlyRecommended:=False)
  oDoc.Close()
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Convert method of the document object converts the document to the latest version of the .docx format supported by the version of Word that you are using.

Whether you notice much difference visually will depend on what is in your document. You may notice that if Word was displaying "Compatibility mode" in the document's title bar before, that may disappear, and if you look inside the .docx you may see differences, e.g. in the XML namespace URIs, some details of the encoding, and so on.

The method is (sort of) documented [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff835714.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396).